# vba Looping through Shape Listbox (change type)

Tags: vba, listbox, shapes, itemscontrol

So I have this spreadsheet with several listboxes. In these listboxes I have some values/items that are actually filters. I want to get each item/filter of each listboxes to amend an SQL query in my code.
So I've been asked to looped through the listboxes and I managed to do it by looping the Shapes of the spreadsheet but eventually ... those listboxes are now viewed as Shapes in VBA and not listboxes anymore. I'm looking for a way to either turn my shape in listbox or maybe find a method from the Shapes type to loop each listbox's items. Here is the part of my code, so far I loop through each shapes/listboxes, if within my shapes'name there is the word "CFRA" then I want to loop within each item selected of my listbox so that my function return them.

```
Private Function getListFilters() As String

    My_Sheet.Activate
    Dim Shp
    For Each Shp In My_Sheet.Shapes
        pos = InStrRev(Shp.Name, "CFRA", , vbTextCompare)
        MsgBox (pos)
        If pos <> 0 Then
        MsgBox (TypeName(Shp))

        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Thanks in advance for those who are willing to help me and have a great day :)

Comment: Are they Form or ActiveX type?

Comment: Hi @FaneDuru, they are ActiveX, direct listboxes within the Spreadsheet

Comment: Do you want looping between "selected items"? Is your list of Multiselect type? If yes, how do you like the string to be returned by the function to be built?

Comment: @FaneDuru yes exactly this is Multiselect type

Comment: You answer my question only partial... You missed the most important part: "how do you like the string to be returned by the function to be built"?

Comment: I adapted the code to retrieve all selected items in the found list. They are loaded in an array and finally the array is joined in a string, elements separated by "|". You can join its content in the way you need. If you have a problem, from this point of view, I can help, too...

Comment: @FaneDuru, to answer this, yes, in one function would be nice but the way you put it below makes its effect

Comment: The function can be easily adapted to be in one piece. I thought you want understanding the way it works. But, OK, I will make it in two, three minutes...

Comment: I added to my answer your modified function, able to return a string of the list box selected items...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you do not explain what is to be extracted from the list box, try the next `Function`, please. It will deliver the list box object having "CFRA" string in its name. Of course, any string can be used:

```
Private Function getListObjX(strPartName As String, sh As Worksheet) As MSForms.ListBox
    Dim oObj As OLEObject
    For Each oObj In sh.OLEObjects
      If oObj.Name Like "*" & strPartName & "*" Then
          'Debug.Print oObj.Name, TypeName(oObj.Object): Stop
          If TypeName(oObj.Object) = "ListBox" Then
             Set getListObjX = oObj.Object: Exit Function
          End If
      End If
   Next
End Function
```

It can be called in the next way:

```
Sub testGetListObj()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lstB As MSForms.ListBox, lstBF As ListBox
  Dim i As Long, arrSel As Variant, k As Long
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   
   Set lstB = getListObjX("CFRA", sh)
   If lstB Is Nothing Then MsgBox "No such an ActiveX list box...": Exit Sub
   ReDim arrSel(lstB.ListCount - 1)
   
   For i = 0 To lstB.ListCount - 1
        If lstB.Selected(i) Then
            'Debug.Print lstB.List(i)
            arrSel(k) = lstB.List(i): k = k + 1
        End If
   Next i
   ReDim Preserve arrSel(k - 1)
   MsgBox Join(arrSel, "|")
End Sub
```

But, being an ActiveX list box type, **you can simply use one of its events**. Of course, if you do not need to take items from more then a list box...

I also prepared a function to return the object for a Form list box (before you clarify the issue). Maybe, somebody else will use it...

```
    Dim oObj As ListBox
    For Each oObj In sh.ListBoxes 'even not being shown by intellisense, this collection exists...
      If oObj.Name Like "*" & strPartName & "*" Then
          'Debug.Print oObj.Name
          Set getListObjF = oObj: Exit Function
      End If
   Next
End Function
```

It can be called similarly, but the `lstB` should be declared `As ListBox`.

Edited, **to make the function working in one step**:

```
Private Function getListFilters(strPartName) As String
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lstB As MSForms.ListBox
   Dim oObj As OLEObject, i As Long, arrSel As Variant, k As Long
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet ' use here your sheet
   
    For Each oObj In sh.OLEObjects
      If oObj.Name Like "*" & strPartName & "*" Then
          If TypeName(oObj.Object) = "ListBox" Then
             Set lstB = oObj.Object: Exit For
          End If
      End If
   Next
   If lstB Is Nothing Then MsgBox "No such an ActiveX list box...": Exit Function
   ReDim arrSel(lstB.ListCount - 1)
   
   For i = 0 To lstB.ListCount - 1
        If lstB.Selected(i) Then
            arrSel(k) = lstB.List(i): k = k + 1
        End If
   Next i
   ReDim Preserve arrSel(k - 1)
   getListFilters = Join(arrSel, "|")
End Function
```

And the function will be simple called as:

```
Debug.Print getListFilters("CFRA")
```

Comment: thank you so much for that, it helps a lot ! But MSForms concern only Listboxes within a formulaire isn't that right ?

Comment: @Pierre_CM: Not really... MSForms means all ActiveX controls from a worksheet OLEObjects or from a Form.. The code iterates between all ActiveX (OLEObjects) controls and `Set` as `ListBox` the `Object` of the one meeting name criteria and its Type (ListBox). Should I understand that my code did not answer your question?

Comment: @Pierre_CM: Now, the above code put in an array all selected items of the found list box  and finally the array is joined, using "|" separator and shown in a message box. Is this what you need? The advantage of using the function to obtain the CheckBox object is the fact that you can use Intellisense in order to select between such an object properties, methods  etc.

Comment: i testeds your code, thanks for this ! However, I have the feeling that  you need to run it several times as in the getListObjX function you exit the code as soon as you cross a list including "CFRA" and  that is Listbox type you exit the function and then loop on the result in testGetListObj.

Comment: @Pierre_CM:  Did you refresh the page (this one)? What `testGetListObj` are you talking about? I placed a new function, exactly named like yours. And about exiting, should I understand that there would be more list boxes having the same string in their name (like "CFRA" of the example), and all of them must be returned? If yes, this will not be a problem to adapt, but did you mentioned something about such an issue and I missed it?

Comment: After running again, for example I have a listBox name CFRA_Rating with ratings from 1 to 5 and only 4 selected. I run your code and the output is "4". The code run but it get the exit in the "For each" loop as soon as it cross the Rating Listbox without retun the other listboxes

Comment: thank you so much for you help, you got me searching for info that I didn't have. However, for this particular question, FunThomas's piece of code is displaying all the listboxes of the sheet with their selected items.
But thanks again, with your help I understand better the concept of objects in VBA !

Comment: @Pierre_CM: I cannot get you... I asked you a very clear question: " should I understand that there would be more list boxes having the same string in their name (like "CFRA" of the example), and all of them must be returned"? If the answer is, yes, even if you did not mention anything about this issue, it is enough to comment `Exit For`. If there are not more such list boxes, **why do you need to lose time iterating in vain**?  `Exit For` is used for efficiency...

Comment: it's ok man, yes I checked without it after and it worked :) You code is nice, the other one is just smaller but your idea is good ! Pardon me if I did not answer to your question but in my first request  I stated that I had several listboxes with the pattern "CFRA" that's why I wasn't sure on what you asked me. 
And as I told you, thank you so much for your help, you added some code that forces me to go and check on the concepts etc... a the end everybody got it and that's what really matters ;)

Answer (score 0):

You access `ActiveX`-Objects via the `OLEObjects`-Collection of a worksheet. The interesting control information are in the property `Object` of such an object:

- Use VBA function `TypeName` to figure out what kind of OLE object you have
- Number of items can be fetched with the `Object.ListCount` property.
- To access the items of a listbox, loop over the `Object.list` property (index starts at 0, so loop must run from 0 to ListCount-1)
- To check if an item is selected, use the matching .Object.Selected property.

The following code will loop will print all selected items of all listboxes of a worksheet:

```
Sub listBoxes()
    Dim objx As OLEObject
    For Each objx In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
        Debug.Print "Name = " & objx.Name & "  Typ = " & TypeName(objx.Object)
        If TypeName(objx.Object) = "ListBox" Then
            Dim i As Long
            For i = 0 To objx.Object.ListCount - 1
                If objx.Object.Selected(i) Then
                    Debug.Print objx.Name, objx.Object.list(i)
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**Update**: To show the coherence between *Shapes*, *OleObjects* and *ActiceX* controls on a sheet:

A **Shape** is a container for everything that is not part of a cell/range. Could be any kind of painted shape forms (rectangels, arrows, stars...), could be an image, a chart, an OLEObject, a form control and so on.

An **OLEObject** is a something that is not from Excel but is put into an Excel sheet, using a technique called OLE, [Object Linking and Embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Linking_and_Embedding).

An **ActiveX** is a control (editbox, listbox...). These controls where developed by Microsoft and where meant to run in different environments (eg a browser). They are accessible via dll and this dll is added into Excel and other office programs.

Every ActiveX-Control is added as an OLEObject into a sheet, but you can have also different OLEObjects (eg an embedded Word document) that are not an ActiceX objects.

When you want to access those things via VBA, you can use the `Shapes`-collection that lists all shapes of a sheet (including all OLEObjects), or you can use the `OLEObjects`-collection that lists all OLEObjects (including all ActiveX controls). However, there is no ActiveX collection, so if you want to fetch all ActiceX-Controls, you have to loop over either the two collections mentioned above.

If you want to access an OLEObject from the shape collection, you first need to check the type of the shape, it must have the type `msoOLEControlObject` (12) or `msoEmbeddedOLEObject` (7). A list of all shape types can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msoshapetype).

If the shape is either 7 or 12, you can access the `OLEObject` using `Shape.OLEFormat.Object`. The following to loops results in exactly the same (`ws` is just a worksheet variable)

```
Dim sh As Shape, oleObj As OLEObject
For Each sh In ws.Shapes
    If sh.Type = msoOLEControlObject Or sh.Type = msoEmbeddedOLEObject Then
        Set oleObj = sh.OLEFormat.Object
        Debug.Print oleObj.Name, oleObj.OLEType
    End If
Next

For Each oleObj In ws.OLEObjects
    Debug.Print oleObj.Name, oleObj.OLEType
Next
```

Note that sh.Name and sh.OLEFormat.Object.Name are not necessarily the same.

Now the last step is to find the ActiveX-Controls of a specific type, this was already shown in the code of the original answer above - the ActiveX-control can be accessed via `oleObj.object`. Check the object type if the VBA function `TypeName` to filter out for example your listboxes.

Comment: Thank you @FunThomas ! This is my piece of code in a much better ... shape :) 
By theway, would you mond to tell me what's the difference between ActiveX Objects and OLEObjects ?

Comment: I think you can OLEObjects that are not ActiveX Objects, but ActiveX objects are part of the OLEObjects collection. From you perspective, you can use them as synonyms.

Comment: yeah I understand that OLEobject seem to be all the objects and ActiveX objects are simply ActiveX controls. But in my case, Shape was an OLEObject and Litsbox was an ActiveX one

Comment: Updated the answer to explain some details - hope I got them right.